# How to seperate React application from Ruby on Rails created with webpack configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

I found an open source Ruby on Rails project that is created with command `rails new myapp --webpack=react` but I am only interested in the React part. How can I seperate it from the rest and enable it to run on its own?

The link to repo: https://github.com/vigetlabs/storyboard

For what I have done so far;
React related files reside in directory `./app/javascript/pack/` but npm script triggers Ruby application first. Ruby, somehow, starts the React application. This is how far I could come.

Answer (score 0):

1. use create-react-app to create a new react app.
2. copy and paste `/app/javascript/src` to the newly created react app. maybe `packs` folder too.
3. copy over the `package.json` file content to get all packages.
4. do some testing/debugging